# YouTube API Get all videos uploaded feed

Tags: java, api, youtube

I can't seem to retrieve ALL videos from a particular channel on YouTube, despite the API giving example code that should perform just that. I'm using Java.

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers/uploads

The above rss feed is the URL they [suggest using](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#Retrieving_Uploads) along with the following sample code..

```
    /*init the list*/
    String feedUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers/uploads";
    VideoFeed videoFeeder = null;
    videoFeeder = serviceobject.getFeed(new URL(feedUrl), VideoFeed.class);
```

Looping this with a for loop suggests 25 entries (as per the RSS).

However - the actual number of videos uploaded is significantly larger. (662 at time of writing).  My query is how on earth you retrieve everything with the API, not just a subset of the data. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong? Should I be using a different URL?
http://www.youtube.com/GoogleDevelopers#g/a

---

Never mind. Twas a case of RTFM. Needed to page the results.

Comment: did you find anything for this @Paul

Comment: Yes. I just needed to page the returned resultset, which provides a (getNextLink) method. See: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#Pagination for the general gist.